# What is the difference between random and sequential sampling from the reply memory?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn, experience-replay

I was working on an RL problem and I am confused at one specific point. We use **replay memory** so that the network learns about previous actions and how these actions lead to a success or a failure.

Now, to train the neural network, we use batches from this replay or experience memory. But here's my confusion.

Some places like [this](https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/Bcuj2fTH4_4) extract random (non-sequential) batches from the memory to train the neural network but [Andrej Karpathy](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/a4166c7fe253700972fcbc77e4ea32c5) uses the sequential data to train the network.

Can someone tell me why there's the difference?

Comment: You linked 2 completely different algorithms, that is the reason why there is a difference. One is off-policy and other is on-policy algorithm

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: First link talks about DQN algorithm, second link is implementation of policy gradient algorithm, reinforcement learning isn't only a single algorithm there are multiple kinds of algorithms, you need to read up a bit on it

Comment: @Brale_, so correct me if I'm wrong. in DQN, the sequence doesn't matter because we have this Q table that gives an idea to the network what it should do to converge. But in PG, we don't have such a table or any reference hence we have to follow the sequence to see which set of actions led to an optimal policy?